# How to add a default controller with a dash in the name in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a ASP.NET (targeted to .NET Framework 4.7) website with C# and Razor in Visual Studio 2017. I am using the *ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)* template with the *MVC* setup.

Without modification, the template provides a website template with the following page tree (as seen from the web visitor):

- `/` *(Controller `Home`, Action `Index`)*

  - `/Home/About` *(Controller `Home`, Action `About`)*
  - `/Home/Contact` *(Controller `Home`, Action `Contact`)*

To fulfill SEO requirements, I need to make "Home" within the URL to be "Site-Name", including a dash. The result should be like this (as seen from the web visitor):

- `/` *(Controller `Home`, Action `Index`)*

  - `/Site-Name/About` *(Controller `Home`, Action `About`)*
  - `/Site-Name/Contact` *(Controller `Home`, Action `Contact`)*

From my experiments, I only get managed to have a custom action name, but could not get the controller name to work. Renaming the *Home* controller to *Site-Name* would not work, as a dash is not a valid class name character.

How to achieve the desired URL scheme for the default controller?

PS: How to add controllers (URL part) with a dash in general?

Comment: `RoutePrefixAttribute` will result in the index page will be not found and to get the index page, I have to go to `/Site-Name/Index`.

Comment: yes, sorry, posted comment and realised that you use old convention routing

Comment: then, just add extra route before default route `routes.MapRoute("SeoDefault","Site-Name/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });`

Comment: @vasily.sib : While your solutions works, `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")` does not point to the root URL path anymore. It will always point to `/Site-Name`. Any suggestion to fix this cosmetic issue? The actual `/` mapps to `/Site-Name`. However, I would prefer to have `/` as the target for `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")`. `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "About", "Home")` however should point to `/Site-Name/About`.

Comment: for example you may use another helper: `@Html.RouteLink("Home", "Default");`